# One Function for Multiple Variables

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement, local-storage

I am making a sign up sheet app. There are several time slots one can write their name into and submit, showing their name where they have entered it at the corresponding time.

So far I can only get the function to do one name at a time. Is there a way to have it do the same function but for each time slot? Each input field has a corresponding `<li>` where I wish the input.value to appear. I am trying a switch() to no avail here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

```
function addName(e) {
switch(e) {
case 0:
      scheduleThree.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputThree.value));
      storeNameInLocalStorage(inputThree.value);
      break;
case 1:
      scheduleThreeTwoFive.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputThreeTwoFive.value));
      storeNameInLocalStorage(inputThreeTwoFive.value);
      break;
  }
}
```

For reference this is the working code for the function to run once. I know there must be a way to do it without writing new functions for each of the 12 time slots.

```
function addName(e) {
    if(inputThree.value === '') {
      // alert('Please enter your name');
    } else {
      scheduleThree.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputThree.value));
      storeNameInLocalStorage(inputThree.value);
    }
  }

  function storeNameInLocalStorage(name) {
    let names;
    if(localStorage.getItem('names') === null){
        names = [];
    } else {
        names = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('names'));
    }
    names.push(name);
    localStorage.setItem('names', JSON.stringify(names));
}

function getNames() {
    let names;
    if(localStorage.getItem('names') === null){
        names = [];
    } else {
        names = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('names'));
    }

    names.forEach(function(name){
    scheduleThree.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
    inputThree.remove();
    inputThreeParent.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name))
    })
}
```

Comment: Here's the basic idea: https://jsfiddle.net/yrebpqn0/

Comment: That's an interesting solution. Thank you!